# How does one use a Stepper to update a value in the model in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to increment or decrement a value using Stepper, however I cannot fathom how to take the new value and update my model.

I've also tried to use the onIncrement, onDecrement version, but here there appears to be no option to disable the + or - when the range has been reached.

Here's my example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var updateAge = UpdateAge()
    @State private var showAgeEditor = false
    
    @State var age: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// Show the current age.
            Text("Age \(age)")
            Image(systemName: "keyboard")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showAgeEditor = true
            }
            /// Present the sheet to update the age.
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAgeEditor) {
                SheetView(showAgeEditor: self.$showAgeEditor)
                .environmentObject(self.updateAge)
                .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 400)
                                               }
        }
        /// Calls the viewModel (UpdateAge) to fetch the age from the model.
            .onAppear(perform: {self.age = self.updateAge.withAge})
    }
}


struct SheetView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var updateAge: UpdateAge
    @Binding var showAgeEditor: Bool
    /// Steppers state.
    @State private var age: Int = 18
    let maxAge = 21
    let minAge = 18
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("Age of person = \(age)")
            /// When I increment or Decrement the stepper I want the Age to increase or decrease.
            Stepper<Text>(value: $age, in: minAge...maxAge, step: 1) {
                /// And when it does, to store the value in the model via the viewModel.
                /// However I appear to have created an infinite loop. Just uncomment the line below.
//                self.updateAge.with(age: age)
                /// Then display the value in the label.
                return Text("\(age)")
                
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {self.age = self.updateAge.withAge})
    }
}

class UpdateAge: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = Model()
    
    func with(age value: Int) {
        print("Value passed \(value)")
        self.model.setDrinkingAge(with: value)
    }
    
    var withAge: Int {
        get { model.drinkingAge }
    }
}

struct Model {
    var drinkingAge: Int = 18
    mutating func setDrinkingAge(with value: Int) {
        drinkingAge = value
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to model directly via view model projected value, like below (so local state `age` is redundant)

```
Stepper(value: $updateAge.model.drinkingAge, in: minAge...maxAge, step: 1) {
    Text("\(updateAge.model.drinkingAge)")
}
```